# How can I set some css to a react NumPad component?

Tags: css, reactjs, numpad

I have a react numpad component in my code and I need to change its size, but I cannot modify its `CSS`, `theme` or something like that properly.

I've already realized that some style like colors or fonts may be changed in `node_modules\react-numpad\build`, but omething like `size` or `align` I cannot change. Somebody help me, please , after looking to the following template code.

```
import NumPad from 'react-numpad';

<NumPad.Number
    onChange={(value) => { console.log('value', value)}}
    label={'Total'}
    placeholder={'my placeholder'}
    value={100}
    decimal={2}
/>
```

When we click on the component, we get the numpad open. I need this numpad to be something much bigger than the standard one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `Numpad` is dynamically added to the document.

You can change it's `CSS`. If you inspect it, you will get a element with `MuiPaper-root` class, using this class name you can change it's `CSS`.

```
.MuiPaper-root{
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    font-size: 25px;    
}
```

If you want to change color of number being displayed you can do this,

```
.MuiPaper-root .MuiButtonBase-root{
    color:blue;
}
```

Like this you can change `CSS` for whatever you want.

**Note:** Don't change any `CSS` directly in `node_modules` folder, instead you can override the `CSS` in your custom `CSS` file.

Comment: Sorry, where can I find this `MuiPaper-root`. I could not find in the build folder.

Comment: After I override the `MuiPaper-root` class in my css, should I define the component like the following? `<NumPad.Number className="MuiPaper-root"`

Comment: When your Numpad open, it add's div dynamically which contains class name `MuiPaper-root`. You don't have to explicitly write the class name.

Comment: When Numpad is open you can right click on that to inspect the element and you can see the div with `MuiPaper-root` added to document.

Comment: It is pre defined class nam you just need to add css given above in your css file